# Vuetify - How to align app-bar text to center

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue3/Vuetify3, I'm trying to align the text of the app-bar to the center, but for some reason when I try to add `text-center` to the `v-app-bar-title` like so:

`<div class="d-flex align-center text-center">`

and/or I append the `text-center` on to the div or to the `v-container`, nothing successfully makes the`v-app-bar-title` text centered.

I tried one thing that worked, which was removing the existing `div` classes and just adding `text-center`, but I'm assuming this will mess with responsiveness since afaik `d-flex` and `align-center` are required for it?

Any explanations and/or suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar>
      <v-container class="d-flex align-center py-0">
        <v-app-bar-title class="pl-0">
          <div class="d-flex align-center">
            <v-avatar
              rounded="0"
              class="mr-3"
              image="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/docs/images/logos/v.png"
            />

            Example Sentence that should be centered
          </div>
        </v-app-bar-title>
      </v-container>
    </v-app-bar>
```

Comment: If you want to align it using d-flex you should use "justify-center" for horizontal alignment and align-center it's use for vertical

Answer (score 1):

the flexbox helpers override `text-center`.  you can use `justify-center` with flexbox, or remove the flex classnames and just use `text-center`

```html
<v-app-bar-title class="pl-0">
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-avatar
      rounded="0"
      class="mr-3"
      image="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/docs/images/logos/v.png"
    />
    Example Sentence that should be centered
  </div>
</v-app-bar-title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `justify-center` class to center the content , `text-center` will center text but not your container if you're using flexbox. You can take a look at this vuetify documentation
[Vuetify CSS Flex Helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex-justify)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this requirement by using the margin helper class available [`here`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/#negative-margin) in Vue 3 style documentation.

Live Demo (As facing some challenge to create a below code snippet in Vuetify 3, I am demoing it by using Vuetify 2) **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.13/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.13/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-app-bar
        color="deep-purple accent-4"
        dense
        dark
      >
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
        <v-toolbar-title class="mx-auto">Page title</v-toolbar-title>
      </v-app-bar>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```